# Need assistance in rare battery identification

Tags: batteries, identification

Whilst looking for a battery for one of my many projects, I found this small battery in a box of parts I had - I have looked everywhere I know online so far and have not found anything close, apart from a 12v 23A rf remote battery.

These batteries are 1.2v and 28mm long and 10mm across. Very similar to a AAA but half the height. No identification apart from a chinese battery manufacturer that no longer exists.

Would anyone be able to identify this cell?

[image: battery]

Comment: Don't short them out with your calipers! That one is probably flat though.

Comment: What's the point here?  It's some small cylindrical cell, perhaps envisioned as a fraction of an AAA or perhaps simply custom.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no problem which actually needs solving

Comment: Is it an 'N' cell perhaps?   I haven't seen one of those in a long time.

Comment: Are you sure that it is 1.2V or could it be 12V? Car remote starter key fobs usually use a 12V battery about the size of a "N" cell (about half the length of a "AA" cell. I don't recall the part number but I still have a box or two at my shop. I can find out tomorrow if you still need the information.

Comment: This is the battery from the answer below - Thanks very much for your help with this - Bit annoying how some locations get far better google search results than me .... https://www.batteriesplus.co.uk/acatalog/1_2_AAA_Size_150_mAh_NiMH_Tagged_Battery.html

Comment: @Transistor Plastic vernier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's half the length of an AAA battery, simply google "1/2AAA battery" and see what you can find, [for example : this](https://www.batteriesplus.co.uk/acatalog/1_2_AAA_Size_150_mAh_NiMH_Tagged_Battery.html)

Comment: That didn't appear on my half AAA search - Thanks!